# Silverlight Enabled WCF Services | Hosted in Website Type Project | .Net 4.0 | Crossdomain Issue

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, web, project

I need a little help regarding WCF Services. Situation is something like this, I have made a website project in .net 4.0 and then I added a Silverlight-Enabled WCF service with the name AdminService.svc. I wrote a few methods in this service, of course, made them [OperationContracts]. Then I created another Silverlight 5.0 project in the same workspace and tried to consume the service (AdminService.svc), added it's reference in this project (We have to keep in mind that AdminService is running in another website type project in the same workspace). But now everytime I run the application and try to call a method which simply return some data, I get this error !

An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI

> 'http://localhost:2850/XYZServices/AdminService.svc'. This could be
>   due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a
>   proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable
>   for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to
>   publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows
>   SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by
>   using internal types in the web service proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception
>   for more details.

Obvious answer to this problem is to add a crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml, right? I have both of them in place in my wcf website type project at the root level with the following content,

clientaccesspolicy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

and the other one

crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Kindly help me out of this, it's becoming troublesome now.

Comment: See "This could be" in the error message. It does not say that this is for sure the error. Very likely, it is something completetly different and actually thanks to an invalid web service definition. Show the code and configuration of your service. Also, what does the service URL show if you manually enter it into a browser?

Comment: Check out my answere here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687492/how-to-consume-wcf-in-silverlight-app/8689291#8689291, maybe it'll help you.

Comment: And here is the answer !

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3901660/614889

I needed to change the web root of the Web Services Project to "/" and it worked for me while on the development server. That means, while being in the visual studio, since there is no web root yet, making the root to "/" was holding the key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that a single error in the clientaccesspolicy.xml file can cause this message.

When copying the content of the file of a web page (blog, MSDN) to Visual Studio sometime you'll get the wrong quote characters or hidden/invisible unicode characters.

Copying the content of the xml file to notepad and pasting it back into Visual Studio solved this issue for me many times.

You can also use the [Silverlight Client Access Policy File Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0b45f55e-e11f-4fcb-977c-58ddabf061e7?SRC=VSIDE) in Visual Studio (Tools | Extension Manager)

Comment: Thanks Erno for replying, I posted the answer above in the comments of the question, I first tried to recheck my policy files, they were find. Thanks anyway !